# JSON framework error

Tags: exception, cordova, salesforce, json-framework

I am trying to run the salesforce ios phonegap app for mobile sdk 
project named

https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/tree/master/hy...

The app starts but stops with the Exception:

```
2012-01-09 17:18:15.897 VFConnector[1354:207] -[NSCFString JSONValue]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5aac9b0 
2012-01-09 17:18:15.916 VFConnector[1354:207] *** Terminating app due 
to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '- 
[NSCFString JSONValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 
0x5aac9b0' 
*** Call stack at first throw: 
( 
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x01a775a9 
__exceptionPreprocess + 185 
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01bcb313 
objc_exception_throw + 44 
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x01a790bb - 
[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187 
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x019e8966 ___forwarding___ + 
966 
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x019e8522 
_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50 
        5   VFConnector                         0x00004af3 - 
[SalesforceOAuthPlugin populateOAuthProperties:] + 99 
        6   VFConnector                         0x00003a8d - 
[SalesforceOAuthPlugin authenticate:withDict:] + 365 
        7   VFConnector                         0x0001772b -[PhoneGapDelegate 
execute:] + 434 
        8   VFConnector                         0x00002d67 - 
[SFContainerAppDelegate execute:] + 71 
        9   VFConnector                         0x00017150 -[PhoneGapDelegate 
executeQueuedCommands] + 265 
        10  VFConnector                         0x000171fd -[PhoneGapDelegate 
flushCommandQueue] + 81 
        11  VFConnector                         0x0001756c -[PhoneGapDelegate 
webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:] + 822 
        12  VFConnector                         0x00003060 - 
[SFContainerAppDelegate 
webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:] + 96 
        13  UIKit                               0x004bea92 -[UIWebView 
webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:] 
+ 291 
        14  CoreFoundation                      0x019e7c7d __invoking___ + 29 
        15  CoreFoundation                      0x019e7b51 -[NSInvocation 
invoke] + 145 
        16  CoreFoundation                      0x01a15858 -[NSInvocation 
invokeWithTarget:] + 72 
        17  WebKit                              0x025d8c76 - 
[_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] + 182 
        18  CoreFoundation                      0x019e8a04 ___forwarding___ + 
1124 
        19  CoreFoundation                      0x019e8522 
_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50 
        20  CoreFoundation                      0x019e7c7d __invoking___ + 29 
        21  CoreFoundation                      0x019e7b51 -[NSInvocation 
invoke] + 145 
        22  WebCore                             0x030cc150 
_ZL20HandleDelegateSourcePv + 64 
        23  CoreFoundation                      0x01a588ff 
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15 
        24  CoreFoundation                      0x019b688b 
__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 571 
        25  CoreFoundation                      0x019b5d86 __CFRunLoopRun + 
470 
        26  CoreFoundation                      0x019b5840 
CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208 
        27  CoreFoundation                      0x019b5761 CFRunLoopRunInMode 
+ 97 
        28  GraphicsServices                    0x021141c4 GSEventRunModal + 
217 
        29  GraphicsServices                    0x02114289 GSEventRun + 115 
        30  UIKit                               0x00335c93 UIApplicationMain 
+ 1160 
        31  VFConnector                         0x00002777 main + 135 
        32  VFConnector                         0x000026e5 start + 53 
        33  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1 
) 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Please Help because I am stuck on this for 2 days!

Comment: Have you got all the dependencies installed correctly? I know id requires SBJson for example.

Comment: yup. there was a problem with dependency involving JSON framework. i removed it and it all worked well.

Comment: Glad to know it got fixed. Will add an answer for others to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a JSON library dependency issue. Ensure all the JSON libraries required are installed.